# How can I execute a batch process in hook_install()?

Tags: 9

When my module is installed, I need to execute a batch process, loading hundreds of entities and doing stuff with them.

This is trivial with [hook_post_update_NAME()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_post_update_NAME/9.3.x) and its `$sandbox` variable. How can I achieve the same sort of thing via [hook_install()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!module.api.php/function/hook_install/9.3.x)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a custom module you can use `hook_deploy_NAME(&$sandbox)` inside MY_MODULE.deploy.php. `drush deploy:hook` being executed as part of `drush deploy` will pick up any `hook_deploy_NAME` implementation even of just recently enabled modules.

So make sure you execute `drush deploy` as part of your deployment routine, then your custom module will get enabled first from `drush cim` (and an entry in the core.extension.yml of course) and your custom install logic will get run from `drush deploy:hook` being executed after it.

Found out just recently that `hook_deploy_NAME` implementations won't get registered on module enablement like `hook_update_N` implementations are. Every existing `hook_deploy_NAME` implementation will just be picked up.

Talked about it quickly with Moshe Weitzman (the Drush maintainer) on Drupal Slack asking if this is a bug and he said no it's a feature and that `hook_deploy_NAME` implementations are supposed to only be used in custom modules.

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/254411/15055 for all the commands that are part of `drush deploy`.

---

Have you tried `batch_set` in the install hook? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/310282/15055

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about `hook_deploy_NAME()`. Unfortunately, this site is not using `drush deploy` yet. And for some reason I didn't think you could use `batch_set` in `hook_install()`, but you totally can.

Comment: I resolved with `batch_set`

Comment: Can you post a full example of your use case?

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf – You mean the full example that's linked in the last line of my post? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/310282/15055